# strange exception with mono droid and mvvm cross Unable to Resolve IoC type

Tags: android, exception, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

We are working with mono droid and mvvmcross and sometimes when the app is initializing we experience a exception- Cirrious.MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Unable to Resolve IoC type. 
It happens when we do a call to GetService() -

```
public IImageService ImageService
        {
            get
            {
                if (_imageService == null)
                {
                    _imageService = this.GetService<IImageService>();

                }
                return _imageService;
            }
        }
```

It seems that it cannot resolve IImageService - Do you guys have any ideas what can cause this and to avoid it?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Unable to Resolve IoC type.' suggests that the `IImageService` implementation cannot be found in the IoC container.

This normally suggests that an implementation for the interface hasn't been registered with the IoC framework before the call to `GetService<>`.

Some questions that might help work out why this is happening:

- How are you registering IImageService as with the IoC? Is it definitely always registered before the `GetService<>` call is made?
- If this occurs 'sometimes', then is there any pattern to when those times occur? I'd normally expect this sort of code to either always work or always fail - for it to fail 'sometimes' suggests maybe some sort of async timing issue?

Comment: I moved the initialization of the service and have not experienced the exception since :)